# How to Lock bootloader in source code- U-boot

Tags: bootloader, u-boot, device-tree

I want to make my development board's bootloader (which is `u-boot`) be locked so no one can stop autoboot process at all. (In this way I will be sure that no one can alter the firmware of the board!)

So please guide me in order to locking the firmware and block any "root" attempts. I am using `amlogic s905x` SoC.

Another question:

Is this process relates to verified boot and signing kernel images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your SoC chip supports secure boot, then it is a way to make its firmware, secure of jail breaking. consult the datasheet. Otherwise you can not 'lock' the firmware.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CONFIG_AUTOBOOT_KEYED=Password to require a password for stopping autoboot.

You can use CONFIG_BOOTDELAY=-2 to autoboot with no delay and not check for abort.

This will not stop users with physical access from altering the firmware. They could simply insert there own SD-card or USB stick or reprogram the eMMC.

CONFIG_AUTOBOOT_KEYED will make you live easier if you need to reflash a returned device.

Comment: You said 'This will not stop users with physical access from altering the firmware..' How can I prevent them from altering firmware and rooting it permanently? Is verified boot enabling sufficient? Thank you. @xypron